# How can I get the terminal key code in vim

Tags: linux, macos, vim, key, keyboard-shortcuts

I have an existing `.vimrc` which was created on macintosh computer and contains mappings like this:

```
"------------------------------------------------------------
" keyboard shortcuts
"------------------------------------------------------------

nmap <S-Tab> :wincmd W<CR>
nmap <S-q> :bp\|bd #<CR>
nmap « :bp\|bd #<CR>
nmap ¢ :sp<CR>
nmap ¶ :vsp\|wincmd w<CR>
nmap :Q :qa<CR>
nmap :W :wqa<CR>
nmap ≠ :q<CR>
nmap ESC[1;9B 15j
nmap ESC[1;9A 15k
nmap ^? :w<CR>
nmap ø :edit
nmap ESC[1;5B 15j
nmap ESC[1;5A 15k
vmap ESC[1;5B 15j
vmap ESC[1;5A 15k
nmap ^\ :edit
nmap ^] :wincmd w<CR>
nmap <F9> :w<CR>:Make<CR><CR>
imap <F9> <ESC>:w<CR>:Make<CR>
nmap <C-n> :cnext<CR>
nmap <C-p> :cprev<CR>
nmap <F5> :Grep
nmap @ g~w w
nmap <F10> :ConqueGdb
nmap ^A :sav %:h/filename
nmap ESC[1;2D :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
nmap ESC[1;2B :sp\|wincmd w<CR>
nmap ESC[1;2C :vsp\|wincmd w<CR>
nmap ESC[1;5D :q<CR>
nmap ESC[1;5F :BuffergatorToggle<CR>

nmap ESC[1;6D w
nmap ESC[1;6B b
```

Now I have transferred this `.vimrc` to a new linux computer (debian-based), but half of the shortcuts don't work anymore. I guess thats because the mac interpretes some of the keystrokes differently as compared to the linux computer (both computers do have vim v8.1).

When creating shortcuts, I remember that there was a function in vim which would print out the key codes when you press the keys, however that was about 10 years ago and I don't remember it, and I can't find via google.
To be precise, it was like "press <kbd>X</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in vim, then press e.g. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, then vim would print the corresponding key code to be used in the mappings".

How can I do this now, in order to make those shortcuts work on linux also?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I see what keys vim thinks I'm hitting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10374615/how-can-i-see-what-keys-vim-thinks-im-hitting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [`:help i_CTRL-V`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/insert.txt.html#i_CTRL-V):

> For special keys, the terminal code is inserted.

For example, in my Gnome Terminal pressing `<C-V><Right>` gives `^[OC` and `<C-V><F12>` gives `^[[24~`.

In general, you should prefer Vim's [`key-notation`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/intro.txt.html#key-notation) whenever possible. If you do need to insert specific escape codes *and* need to support multiple platforms with a single `~/.vimrc`, you can wrap the mapping definitions in conditions like `if has('mac')` or `if $TERM ==# 'screen256-color'`.

Comment: Okay while this *seems* to do what I need, I am having issues with several shortcuts, namely `CTRL-3` and `CTRL-0` (and probably more C-something shortcuts). For those, the above `i <C-V> <C-0>` would print nothing. `i <C-V> <C-3>` would print `^[`. however this seems to be just the arrow key (which was not even pressed), so the shortcut fires in random situations. When I just write `nmap <C-3> :something`, it will not trigger.

Comment: Depending on the terminal, not all Ctrl combinations work; usually just Ctrl + letter.