# Can I use mouse mappings on termux vim?

Tags: vim, termux

I have set in my `~/.vimrc` file the following:

```
set mouse=a
nnoremap <C-LeftMouse> :echo 'Foo'<CR>
```

And according to other questions I assumed this would print Foo every time click on control and then somewhere inside the editor.

I was expecting the mapping to work and print the message but it has no response. It seems like vim doesn't capture the event or the mapping is incorrect. I can't tell if I am missing something

Comment: Does it work outside of termux? (It does for me). Check termux' documentation if it intercepts *Ctrl Click* events.

Comment: Yeah just used my ubuntu distro and everything worked as expected. I am unsure if it's termux not sending mouse events or not.

Comment: Chanced to come across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10374615/796259) today. Maybe that can help you clear things up. FYI, there's a wealth of input related bugs to be found on termux' GitHub page.